In MySQL deep page query, the select * and select [primary key] data are inconsistent. Procedure
Background introduction
MySQL table t_order, total record of 160w
select count(*) from t_order;
order_id is primary key, order_status is Secondary index
show index from t_order;
field order_status data distribution is as follows
select order_status,count(*) as total from t_order group by order_status;
Sql execution comparison
SQL 1:
select order_id from t_order where order_status > 3002 order by order_status limit 349000,10;
SQL 1 Execution result
order_id Sequence number is 1498660 to 1498669
SQL 1 explain
The idx_order_status index is used
SQL 2
select * from t_order where order_status > 3002 order by order_status limit 349000,10;
SQL 2 Execution result
order_id Sequence number is 1746820 to 1746829
SQL 2 explain
The idx_order_status index is not used
I don't understand why the execution results of the two sql are not the same
I want to know which sql execution returned the correct record,
and the cause of this problem and how to solve this problem

I suggest if you want consistent result you include order_id in the order by clause

I tried to do that, but it didn't work

did you try order by order_status,order_id ? in both queries..

I have just tried again and found that yes, there should be a problem with what I wrote earlier ,Thank you for your answer, but I don't understand. Why does this kind of problem occur

if you order by status alone there is no guarantees on the order of any other selected columns , and the optimiser will choose which index to use

order by order_status does not provide the uniqueness, is it? if so then the ordering for the rows in a group with the same order_status value is not defined and may differ from one execution to another.

I observe that this SQL does not use any indexes  >> explain select * from t_order where order_status > 3002 order by order_status,order_id limit 349000,10

the optimiser will choose which index to use - if any

Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information directly to your question as editable text, appropriately formatted (code as code, data as tables, etc)

ok,Thanks for reminding me. I'll pay attention later
